# Retrieve output from a shell call to python in a makefile: is there a missing step?

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following `makefiles`:

```
# bash version
SHELL:=/usr/bin/env bash
H:=$(shell pwd)
install:
        @echo "$H::make.$@: not implemented!"
```

And a python3 version:

```
SHELL:=/usr/bin/env python3
H:=$(shell "import os,sys; print(os.getcwd(),file=sys.stdout)")
install:
        @print("$H::make.$@: not implemented!")
```

The `bash` version works perfectly, whereas the `python3` version works, persay.  However, the path variable `$H` is empty.

A check of the python expression in the shell call confirms it is working python code:

```
python3 -c "import os,sys; print(os.getcwd(),file=sys.stdout)"
//works
```

---

How does one comply with the expected behavior in that `shell` call so that make picks up the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what the shell command you wrote actually does.

This:

```
SHELL:=/usr/bin/env bash
H:=$(shell pwd)
```

causes the equivalent of:

```
/usr/bin/env bash -c 'pwd'
```

to be run.

So, this:

```
SHELL:=/usr/bin/env python3
H:=$(shell "import os,sys; print(os.getcwd(),file=sys.stdout)")
```

causes the equivalent of this to be run:

```
/usr/bin/env python3 -c '"import os,sys; print(os.getcwd(),file=sys.stdout)"'
```

to be run.  A string in Python is just a no-op statement, so this does nothing.

Remove the quotes:

```
H := $(shell import os,sys; print(os.getcwd(),file=sys.stdout))
```

Comment: got it -- checked the quotes with bash not python. figured the parenthesis would be a problem, but it sounds like `$` is the magic character for make; should have kept trying things.

Comment: Parentheses are only a problem if you have a non-even number of parens: GNU make does matching.  If you do, then you should use the alternate form with braces `${shell ...}` instead.  If you have non-matched parens AND braces, then you need to put the script into a variable and use `$(shell $(SCRIPTVAR))` instead.